# Pin vs Box: Why is Box not enough?

Tags: rust

I would like to know examples where keeping a `T` type within `Box` would be unsafe, while within `Pin` it would be safe.

Initially, I thought that `std::marker::PhantomPinned` prevents an instance from being moved around (by forbidding it), but seemingly it does not. Since:

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::marker::PhantomPinned;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    field: u32,
    _pin: PhantomPinned
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new(field: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            field,
            _pin: PhantomPinned,
        }
    }
}

fn func(x: MyStruct) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
    func2(x);
}

fn func2(x: MyStruct) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct::new(5);
    func(x);
}
```

this code is compilable, despite the fact that it moves `MyStruct` from `main` to `func` and etc.

as for `Box` and `Pin` they both keep their contents on the heap, so it does not seem to be subjected to motions.

Thus, I would appreciate if someone elaborated this topic on these questions. Since it is not covered in other questions and docs, what is inherently wrong with just getting by with `Box`.

Comment: Passing a `Box` around doesn't move the heap allocation, but there's nothing stopping someone who holds a mutable reference to the box from moving the data out of the heap allocation.  A `Pin` prevents that.

Comment: @eggyal, moving the data out of the heap allocation? could you provide an example, please? Or you mean `leak`?

Comment: `let mut boxed = Box::new(String::from("a")); let moved_string = *boxed;` or even `let moved_string = std::mem::replace(&mut boxed, String::from("b"));`.  (Okay `Box<String>` is stupid, but I couldn't think of simpler non-`Copy` type to use as an example in a comment).

Comment: `Pin` is not useful when you can uphold the invariant by yourself. `Pin` is for interacting with code *you didn't write* that has to be able to use, but not move, the inner type. `Pin` is also not for avoiding unsafety; in fact, `Pin` is *totally useless* if not paired with some `unsafe` somewhere. You're not using `unsafe`, and you're not exposing a public API for other code to use, so `Pin` is doubly useless to you.

Comment: Added the requested example on how to move a value out of `Box` to my answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you misunderstand.

`PhantomPinned` does **not** make data immovable. It just says that once the data **is** pinned, it will never be able to be unpinned again.

Therefore, to make data with `PhantomPinned` unmovable, you have to `Pin` it first.

For example, if you create a pinned version of your `MyStruct` variable, you cannot unpin it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let pinned_x = Box::pin(MyStruct::new(5));
    let unpinned_x = Pin::into_inner(pinned_x);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `PhantomPinned` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/main.rs:20:38
    |
20  |     let unpinned_x = Pin::into_inner(pinned_x);
    |                      --------------- ^^^^^^^^ within `MyStruct`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `PhantomPinned`
    |                      |
    |                      required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
note: required because it appears within the type `MyStruct`
   --> src/main.rs:4:8
    |
4   | struct MyStruct {
    |        ^^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `Pin::<P>::into_inner`
   --> /home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/pin.rs:482:23
    |
482 | impl<P: Deref<Target: Unpin>> Pin<P> {
    |                       ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Pin::<P>::into_inner`
```

While with a normal struct, you can unpin it without a problem:

```rust
struct MyUnpinnableStruct;

fn main() {
    let pinned_x = Box::pin(MyUnpinnableStruct);
    let unpinned_x = Pin::into_inner(pinned_x);
}
```

---

### Difference between `Pin` and `Box`

They are both completely different concepts. `Pin` makes sure that the data it points to cannot be moved. `Box` puts something on the heap.

As you can see from the previous examples, both are often used in conjunction, as the easiest way to prevent something from moving is to put it on the heap.

`PhantomPin` causes classes to be `!Unpin`, meaning once they are pinned, they can no longer be unpinned.

You can try to use `Pin` on values on the stack, but you will run into problems quickly. While it works for unpin-able structs:

```rust
struct MyUnpinnableStruct(u32);

fn main() {
    let y = MyUnpinnableStruct(7);
    {
        let pinned_y = Pin::new(&y);
    }
    // This moves y into the `drop` function
    drop(y);
}
```

It fails for structs that contain `PhantomPinned`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct::new(5);
    {
        // This fails; pinning a reference to a stack object
        // will fail, because once we drop that reference the
        // object will be movable again. So we cannot `Pin` stack objects
        let pinned_x = Pin::new(&x);
    }
    // This moves x into the `drop` function
    drop(x);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `PhantomPinned` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/main.rs:24:33
    |
24  |         let pinned_x = Pin::new(&x);
    |                        -------- ^^ within `MyStruct`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `PhantomPinned`
    |                        |
    |                        required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
note: required because it appears within the type `MyStruct`
   --> src/main.rs:4:8
    |
4   | struct MyStruct {
    |        ^^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `Pin::<P>::new`
   --> /home/martin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/pin.rs:482:23
    |
482 | impl<P: Deref<Target: Unpin>> Pin<P> {
    |                       ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Pin::<P>::new`
```

**Update:** Rust `1.68.0` introduced [`std::pin::pin!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/macro.pin.html) which **can** be used to pin items on the stack. It works by taking ownership and hiding the pinned object, making it impossible to access it again after dropping the `Pin`.

---

### `Box` without `Pin`

While the content of `Box` is on the heap and therefore has a constant address, you can still move it back from the heap to the stack, which wouldn't be possible with a `Pin` object:

```rust
// Note that MyData does not implement Clone or Copy
struct MyData(u32);

impl MyData {
    fn print_addr(&self) {
        println!("Address: {:p}", self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // On the heap
    let x_heap = Box::new(MyData(42));
    x_heap.print_addr();

    // Moved back on the stack
    let x_stack = *x_heap;
    x_stack.print_addr();
}
```

```
Address: 0x557452040ad0
Address: 0x7ffde8f7f0d4
```

---

### Enforcing `Pin`

To make sure that an object is pinned in a member function, you can use the following syntax:

```rust
fn print_addr(self: Pin<&Self>)
```

Together with `PhantomPinned`, you now can be 100% sure that `print_addr` will **always** print the same address for the same object:

```rust
use std::{marker::PhantomPinned, pin::Pin};

struct MyData(u32, PhantomPinned);

impl MyData {
    fn print_addr(self: Pin<&Self>) {
        println!("Address: {:p}", self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // On the heap
    let x_pinned = Box::pin(MyData(42, PhantomPinned));
    x_pinned.as_ref().print_addr();

    // Moved back on the stack
    let x_unpinned = Pin::into_inner(x_pinned); // FAILS!
    let x_stack = *x_unpinned;
    let x_pinned_again = Box::pin(x_stack);
    x_pinned_again.as_ref().print_addr();
}
```

In this example, there is absolutely no way to ever unpin `x_pinned` again, and `print_addr` can only be called on the pinned object.

Why is this useful? For example because you can now work with raw pointers, as is required in the `Future` trait.

But in general, `Pin` is only really useful if paired with `unsafe` code. Without `unsafe` code, the borrow checker is sufficient to keep track of your objects.