# What does `Pin<P>` actually do?

Tags: rust

I'm following the [official docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html) to understand what `Pin<P>` means. Quoting verbatim from the docs, we use `Pin` when we want to "prevent(ing) the value referenced by that pointer from being moved unless it implements Unpin." From that, I'm reasoning that pinning primitive types like an `usize` would be pointless because it implements `Unpin` and would thereby bypass any guarantees `Pin` makes.

But I don't understand how `Pin` makes any guarantees. Does `Pin` actually do something at the compiler level that forces the `T` to hold the same address for some lifetime?

I think the answer is no. It seems that `Pin` doesn't actually do anything except it purposefully restricts the APIs available to retrieve `&mut T`. In other words, it sounds like using `Pin` is more of a declarative gesture saying "this `T` should not be moved unless you know what you're doing". I'm stating this because I don't know why it is so dangerous to expose an `&mut T` for pinned T's.

Let's say that (for some reason), it is unsafe to retrieve mutuable references. I see that `DerefMut` is actually implemented for `Pin` but it comes with the catch that `P` must deref into something `Unpin`. Then it the docs suggest that the way to make something not `Unpin` is to add a `PhantomPinned` to the struct. Is this the actual 'magic' of pinning?

Tldr:
My rough guess on what is pinning:

1. We want to prevent the moving of data so we use `Pin`
2. `Pin` doesn't actually do anything, it just sets up restrictive APIs to make getting mutuable references unsafe. Presumably, getting mutuable references breaks pinning.
3. Basically everything is `Unpinned`, thereby making `Pin` worthless. We can only enforce the boundaries `Pin` is trying to setup if we add a `PhantomPinned` to our struct.

Comment: You might want to read the [module documentation of `pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) as well.

Comment: Pretty much correct. The [`Pin::new_unchecked` Safety documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#safety) explains the rules.

Comment: I think `Pin<T>` is only useful if you have some API that takes a `Pin<&mut T>`, because once you see a value of that type you can be sure that if `T` is not `Unpin` then it will never be moved, even though you are allowed to modify the object in any other way.

Comment: _"Presumably, getting mutuable references breaks pinning."_ Indeed it does, because `std::mem::swap()` can be used to move out of an exclusive reference provided you have something to put in its place.

Comment: I've written a pretty long answer which explains some of the philosophy behind `Pin`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72517657/2902833

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't understand how `Pin` makes any guarantees.

`Pin` does not contain in its implementation a mechanism which provides a guarantee. Rather, `Pin` is *how that guarantee is expressed*. It's a means to communicate that a certain pointer is pinned (and to do some simple manipulations on it).

For example, `Box::pin()` or `Box::into_pin()` produce a `Pin<Box<T>>`. To do that, they call `unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(...) }`. `Box<T>` knows how its own implementation works, so `Box<T>` knows that it can make that guarantee, so `Box<T>` provides these *safe* methods to pin a `Box`.

Then, later, other code can receive a `Pin<Box<T>>` (or a `Pin<&mut T>` created from it with `Pin::as_mut()`) and be assured that it is sound to use the `T` in some way that requires pinning.

`Pin` didn't do any computational work, nor does it know *how* to ensure something is pinned in any case. It is just a thing that can be constructed at one point and then used at another.

Simple data types like [`NonZeroU32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/num/struct.NonZeroU32.html) are somewhat analogous — that's also a type which conveys a guarantee (the number is not zero) from one point (where it is constructed) to another (where it is used). But one notable difference is that you can check whether a `u32` is zero before you use it, but you *can't* check whether a pointer is pinned before you use it, because pinning is a fact about *what isn't going to happen in the future,* not something you can check with an algorithm.

> I don't know why it is so dangerous to expose an `&mut T` for pinned `T`'s.

Here's the key fact: `&mut T` does not, by itself, mean that “you cannot move this `T`”. It only means “after you are done, there must still be a valid `T` here”. If you have two `&mut T`s, you can swap them with [`std::mem::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html). With [`replace_with`](https://docs.rs/replace_with/) you can even move the `T` out, manipulate it, then move it back.

All of these things violate the pinning guarantee (that the `T` will have a stable memory location until it is dropped), so they are not allowed by `Pin`. We could imagine a different language which prohibited these swaps and would not need the distinction between `Pin<&mut T>` and `Pin<T>`, but that's not the language Rust is, and it also wouldn't suffice for the distinction made by `Pin<Box<T>>` vs `Box<T>` — that you can't even move it if you own it, if it's pinned.

> Basically everything is `Unpinned`, thereby making `Pin` worthless. We can only enforce the boundaries `Pin` is trying to setup if we add a `PhantomPinned` to our struct.

This is more or less true. The *point* of `Unpin`-by-default is that generic functions can demand to be given `Pin<&mut T>` or similar, thus *enabling* their use with `T`s that need to be pinned, without also creating inconvenience when the `Pin` is not necessary, by making it possible for safe code to make a “meaningless” `Pin` to satisfy the type that generic function wants, when that would not do any harm. `Unpin` is the trait that expresses “moving this after it is pinned will not do any harm”.

You make your type `!Unpin`, by using `PhantomPinned` or some other type, when you plan to rely (usually in unsafe code) on your struct being pinned.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are generally correct about '''Pin''', from my understanding, the purpose of `Pin` is to prevent value referenced by the pointer from being moved even if the underlying type is `movable`, unless the underlying type is `Unpin`.

Simply put, `Pin` is a way to ensure that the underlying value is not moved.

Regarding to your point that **"everything is Unpinned, thereby making Pin worthless"**, many types are `Unpin` by default, but not all types are!

In particular, types that contain raw pointers or references are often `!Unpin`, because moving them could invalidate the reference. So there are definitely cases where `Pin` is useful and necessary, even if many types are `Unpin`.